# GTK: hide and show a widget in a GtkBox show's the widget underneath the GtkBox

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

*edit*: The problem described here seems to be theme related. I'm using Greybird from XUbuntu here.

## The program

In my program you can click a button to create more buttons in a vertical `GtkBox`. If the buttons exceed the visible space a `GtkScrollbar` will be shown:

[image: Example run of the program]

## Problem

When the `GtkScrollbar` is shown for the first time, it dos not show on the side, as it should be; It's shown *below* the buttons:

[image: Erroneous behavior]

This is weird, because the scrollbar is actually inside a horizontal `GtkBox` in a cell *next to* those buttons.

In this state, the buttons are not clickable anymore until either of of the following happens:

- click the scroll bar
- scroll via mouse wheel
- click the window border
- focus another application

## UI Architecture

This is the architecture of my UI:

[image: UI architecture]

Whether the scrollbar is `show`n or not, is decided when the "page-size" property the `GtkAdjustment` is changed.

## Code

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

gboolean
adj_page_sizechanged (GtkAdjustment *adjustment,
                      GdkEvent      *unused,
                      GtkScrollbar  *scrollbar)
{
  gdouble maxValue = gtk_adjustment_get_upper (adjustment);
  gdouble maxSize = gtk_adjustment_get_page_size  (adjustment);

  gboolean show = (maxValue - maxSize >= 0.000001);
  g_object_set (scrollbar, "visible", show, NULL);
  return FALSE;
}



/**
 *  Creates a `automatic` scollbar for `widget`, that will never
 *  overlay (hide) the content of `widget`.
 **/
GtkWidget *
gtkx_scrollable_widget_vertical_new (GtkWidget     *widget,
                                     GtkAdjustment *adjustment_nullable)
{
  GtkWidget *root = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);

  // setup adjustment
  GtkAdjustment * adj_v = adjustment_nullable;
  if (NULL == adj_v)
    adj_v = gtk_adjustment_new (0,0,100,1,10,10);

  // setup scrollbar
  {
    GtkWidget * scrollbar = gtk_scrollbar_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, adj_v);
    g_signal_connect(adj_v, "notify::page-size", G_CALLBACK (adj_page_sizechanged), scrollbar);
    gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (root), scrollbar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  }


  // setup scrollable area
  {
    GtkWidget * scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, adj_v);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), widget);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window),
                                  GTK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_EXTERNAL);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (root), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  }

  return root;
}



void
add_button (GtkButton *button,
            GtkBox    *box)
{
  g_print("add button\n");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box), gtk_button_new_with_label ("b 2"));
  gtk_widget_show_all (GTK_WIDGET (box));
}



GtkWidget *
create_ui()
{
  GtkWidget * action_button = NULL;
  GtkWidget * box_outer     = NULL;
  GtkWidget * box_inner     = NULL;

  box_inner = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);

  action_button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("click me");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (box_inner), action_button);
  g_signal_connect (action_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (add_button), box_inner);

  box_outer = gtkx_scrollable_widget_vertical_new (box_inner, NULL);
  return box_outer;
}




/**
 *  standard stuff. See `create_ui()`
 **/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), -1, 60);

  GtkWidget * ui = create_ui ();
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), ui);


  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
                    G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT (window));

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);


  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

## Notes

- I don't use `GtkScrolledWindow`'s internal scrollbars, because they will overlay the content. I don't want that. Therefore I'm making this implementation.
- I could imagine this to be a bug within GTK. Even if it is, is there a way to work around it?
- I'm running Gtk3.24 under XOrg, XUb 21.04, Theme: Greybird.

*edit*

It looks like this behavior is triggered depending on the theme.

Comment: I am sorry, but it looks right on my system, Linux Mint 20.1.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! Could you add your GTK version?

Comment: I copied your code to my ArchLinux (gtk+ 3.24.30) and it works fine. I've noticed that just when the scroll bar is can be seen as in your buggy image, but then it is immediately moved to the right side. Maybe you are missing a resize event? Or maybe I have an extra event that makes the issue go away? Maybe it comes from the Window Manager?

Comment: Thank you for testing! It very much looks like this is theme related. In Adawaita for example the problem is much more mitigated: https://youtu.be/upk9caJ51xU . I tried `gtk_widget_queue_resize`, but it did make the situation even worse. Even changing styles of the window manager didn't help.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response, it is `3.24.20`